# WCF removing .svc extension

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I'm able to add a ServiceRoute to my WCF .net 4.0 service with a .svc extension by following these posts:

1. [Post 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358760.aspx)
2. [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292908/eliminate-the-svc-in-the-url-of-a-wcf-4-service-using-routes)

However **how can i remove the ".svc" extension?**

My actual service **file** is called **Catalog.svc**

And after following those posts i'm able to access the same service using **csw.svc**

my Global.asa.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("csw.svc", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(CSW_ebRIM_WebService.Catalog)));
}
```

my Web.config:

```
...
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" >
   <serviceActivations>
      <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
           relativeAddress="~/csw.svc"
           service="CSW_ebRIM_WebService.Catalog"/>
   </serviceActivations>          
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
   </modules>
   <handlers>
       <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"/>
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

However if I remove the `.svc` extension from both the global and the `web.config` I get and error saying:

> The registered relativeAddress '~/csw' under section
>   'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations' in
>   configuration file does not have an extension.

If i put back the `.svc` extension on the `web.config` and only remove it from the global I get:

> Value cannot be null. 
>   Parameter name: contract
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: contract

What gives? How can I remove the `.svc` extension?

Comment: If you remove the .svc extension, how is IIS going to know which handler to use to serve the request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ron Jacobs has a great post on the topic - you need to use a `ServiceRoute` to achieve what you're looking for:

- [Using System.Web.Routing with Data Services (OData)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/04/05/using-system-web-routing-with-data-services-odata.aspx)

As he shows in his follow-up post, [WCF Data Services and ServiceRoute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/04/06/wcf-data-services-and-serviceroute.aspx), the resulting service document does indeed also reflect the change and shows the service URL without the `.svc` extension.

This stuff requires the ASP.NET routing support, which is fully present in .NET 4 (and can be bolted on in .NET 3.5 SP1, if needed)

Comment: thanks the post. It is great and simple. I just don't understand what i'm doing wrong because i'm using the ServiceRoute as he describes with no success.

Comment: @capdragon: I see one discrepancy in your code: in your `<serviceActivations>` section in your config, you're adding the `ServiceHostFactory` for the `.svc` extension - that would indicate a SOAP service (e.g. `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding` or something like that). In your `global.asa.cs` however, you're registering the `WebServiceHostFactory` which is the factory used for REST-based service using the `webHttpBinding` ... unfortunately, you're not showing the relevant config sections to show us **what** binding your service is supposed to use ....

Comment: Thanks Mark... that was it, after changing the factory in the global file to match the one in the web.config "ServiceHostFactory", it all works fine now. Thanks again!