# Removing .svc from WCF service results in no endpoints found

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

So today I decided I wanted to remove the .svc file from the WCF service, and started looking online.

Here is the step by step process of what I did:

**Step 1:** I added the global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Authorization", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Authenticator)));
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Miscellaneous", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Misc)));
}
```

Note: Authenticator and Misc are my interface implementation

**Step 2:** I enabled asp.net compatibility

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

**Step 3:** I added `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]` to each of my interface implementation.

**Step 4:** I had to add `[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]` to every method in my interface. I don't know what this does, but it was erroring out without it.

Now it "works" but when I navigate to root/Authorization (Authorization being the name of my first service) it tells me no endpoints are found.

My endpoints are specified in my web.config as such:

```
        <service name="AuthenticatorService.Authenticator">
            <endpoint address="auth" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="AuthEndpoint"
              contract="AuthInterface.IAuthenticator" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MetadataEndpoint"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
```

I'm very new to WCF so it's probably some stupid mistake.

Comment: Um, why did you want to remove the .svc file?

Comment: Because I read that you can, and I didn't like it there.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to learn a new technology the normal way before you start trying to deviate from the standard practice. Especially if you don't have a well-founded reason for your choice (more than just not liking it). If you're feeling stubborn, you could peruse the "Related" links at the right, where you will find [WCF removing .svc extention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354616/wcf-removing-svc-extention), among others.

Comment: You are right, I decided not to do it. No real gain was in it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing two technologies here - in your config, you define `basicHttpBinding` which is a SOAP service - yet, in your service route, you pass in a `WebServiceHost` which is used for the REST services in WCF (based on the `webHttpBinding`).

Try this - just use the "regular" (SOAP-oriented) `ServiceHostFactory` in your `global.asax`  file:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(
       new ServiceRoute("Authorization", 
                        new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Authenticator)));
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(
       new ServiceRoute("Miscellaneous", 
                        new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Misc)));
}
```

Comment: I didn't use this as I scrapped the idea, but this will help anyone who comes looking.