# .svc substitute with a custom extension

Tags: wcf

Is there a way to change the extension of a WCF Service. I have developed a service with the name customservice.svc. I want to change the extension to customerservice.wso. But the same WCF service have to be invoked. How can you do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354616/wcf-removing-svc-extension

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/dec/15/removing-the-svc-extension-from-wcf-rest-urls