# How to publish WSDL for WCF 4.0 service with REST/SOAP endpoints

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

I'm creating a WCF4 service with REST and SOAP endpoints to be hosted in IIS 7.5.
I have used the WCF4 REST template as an example.
However I have a few questions regarding my setup so far.

Here's my webconfig

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="REST">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MEXGET">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MEXGET" name="Project.WebService.VehicleService">
            <endpoint 
                address="" 
                behaviorConfiguration="REST" 
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                contract="Project.WebService.IVehicleService" />
            <endpoint 
                address="soap" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                contract="Project.WebService.IVehicleService" />
            <endpoint 
                address="mex" 
                binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have removed the standardEndpoints section and added endpoints of my own.
There are no .svc files as I've set the routes in the global.asax as shown below

```
private void RegisterRoutes()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("VehicleService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(VehicleService)));
}
```

The help pages can be accessed via http://localhost:1313/ServiceTest/VehicleService/help

I've also used the WCF Test Client to access http://localhost:1313/ServiceTest/VehicleService/mex
which shows the metadata for the SOAP endpoint

But how do I retrieve the WSDL of the service?

With an svc file I can find the wsdl at http://localhost:1313/ServiceTest/VehicleService.svc?wsdl However I do not have a .svc file.
And neither can I find the WSDL at http://localhost:1313/ServiceTest/VehicleService?wsdl or http://localhost:1313/ServiceTest/VehicleService/soap?wsdl

Do I need to add a .svc file if I want to publish WSDL for the SOAP endpoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have managed to get the WSDL working at http://localhost:1313/ServiceTest/VehicleService?wsdl.
The solution was using new ServiceHostFactory instead of new WebServiceHostFactory in the global.asax.
With WebServiceHostFactory you lose the WSDL functionality.

A similar question can be found here:
[ServiceRoute + WebServiceHostFactory kills WSDL generation? How to create extensionless WCF service with ?wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921802/serviceroute-webservicehostfactory-kills-wsdl-generation-how-to-create-extens)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the WSDL by using the mex URL directly from the browser:

```
http://localhost:1313/ServiceTest/VehicleService/mex
```

The WcfTestClient is almost certainly doing that to retrieve the WSDL so it can generate the proxy to the service.