# Get HttpHandler for asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm using asp.net `RouteTable` to register a custom route for a WebService, however asp.net WebServices do not inherit from `IHttpHandler` interface making it it neither simple nor clean to pass the call on to the underlying `HttpHandler`.

Right now, the only official/documented way is to use `WebServiceHandlerFactory` to get the right handler for the service:

```
IHttpHandler handler = new WebServiceHandlerFactory().GetHandler(HttpContext.Current, "*", "url", "path");
```

However, this requires virtual path of the service which is not what I'm looking for! The other workaround I found was actually hacking into `WebServiceHandlerFactory` using reflection and call  the internal `CoreGetHandler` method:

```
var wshf = new WebServiceHandlerFactory();
var coreGetHandler = wshf.GetType().GetMethod("CoreGetHandler", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var httpHandler = (IHttpHandler)coreGetHandler.Invoke(wshf, new object[] { typeof(MyWebService), context, context.Request, context.Response });
```

But it is not an official/documented way to do so and might change in future releases, so my question is that if there's **any** way to get the right `HttpHandler` for an asp.net WebService solely based on its type rather than its virtual path?

Comment: You may not be aware of this, but ASMX web services are a legacy technology. There will not be any future releases. Why not use WCF, which already supports routes?

Comment: Thanks John, do you mean that I could define the WCF routing right in the IIS routing pipeline? Or I have to define routes using WCF bindigs? I'd been using WCF REST web services, however I remember, that it required me to create my own `ServiceHost`/`WebServiceHost` and the bindings, while I'd rather rely on the IIS bindings

Comment: I've never done anything but standard routing with WCF WebServiceHost (a service for Silverlight). My point was simply that WCF is about 100 times as extensible and configurable as ASMX, so there's really no reason to stick with the old tech that has been replaced by WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an alternative to the legacy asmx WebServices, using WCF web services is much more easier and extensible. I finally found the solution how to integrate the WCF service with the IIS routing pipeline [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921802/serviceroute-webservicehostfactory-kills-wsdl-generation-how-to-create-extens)

Here's a quick snippet:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("CustomServiceAddress", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(WCFService)));
```