# MVC Global.asax --> ServiceRoute / WebServiceHostFactory class does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Inside the global.asax of my MVC website I am trying to add a reference for a WCF Service, according to what I found online, I should use something similar to:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

 routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Person", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(PersonService)));

 routes.MapRoute(
     "Default", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

But, even after saying that the class `ServiceRoute` is using the namespace System.ServiceModel.Activation, the compiler still says that is not an existing class.....

The same happens to the class "`WebServiceHostFactory`"... visual studio ask me if I want to create this class......

What am I missing in here?

Comment: Try using `ServiceHostFactory` instead of `WebServiceHostFactory`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Person", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(namespace.PersonService)));
```

Detailed reason is found in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922670/3266029).

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this same problem, and the solution was to add the System.ServiceModel.Activation namespace to my project's references.